# Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to check whether an alert message is present. For that i tried the code,

```
public boolean IsAlertPresent() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            driver.switchTo().alert(); 
            return true; 
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
        { 
            return false; 
        }  
    }
```

But, error messages are shown in boolean and IsAlertPresent(). Boolean shows a message 'Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected' and IsAlertPresent() shows a message 'IsAlertPresent cannot be resolved to a type'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have defined the method **IsAlertPresent()** inside another method. This is not allowed in Java. Define the method separately any your error will go away.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. I placed IsAlertPresent() method inside another method. Now, its working when i placed it outside.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the **IsAlertPresent** method in a jsp file, declare it in the **<%!** section rather than the **<%** section. 
That way the method is part of the jsp class